# como Fechar Word aberto pelo VBA

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6

Para cada Execução da função DeleteSel, um "WINWORD" fica aberto na memoria, mesmo com o comando Close e/ou Quit o mesmo não fecha.

```
Sub DeleteSel(msg As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objBkm As Object

Set objDoc = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objDoc.Visible = True
objDoc.Activate

On Error Resume Next
Set objDoc = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor
Set objBkm = objDoc.Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig")

If Not objBkm Is Nothing Then
    objBkm.Select
    objDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Delete
End If

objDoc.Close
objBkm.Close
Set objBkm = Nothing
Set objDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Alguém teria alguma dica ?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a opção abaixo:

```
objDoc.Quit
```

Ao invés de ".Close"

Antes do "Quit" salve o que for preciso salvar.

Edição 1

#### Exemplo

```
Sub abreWord()

Dim objDoc As Object

Set objDoc = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objDoc.Visible = True
    objDoc.Activate

    objDoc.Quit

    Set objDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

No caso acima o word é aberto e fechado, inclusive o processo winword.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: o Objeto WINWORD continua no Gerenciador do Windows ocupando memoria.

Comment: Ainda que vc coloque `Set objDoc = Nothing`? Qual versão do Office utiliza?

Comment: Sim, mesmo com Quit ou Close o objeto WINWORD fica no gerenciador de tafera. Office 2016.

Comment: Amigo, tente dar um `quit` no `objBkm` também, pois no código que vou atualizar na resposta o winword é fechado normalmente. Vou atualizar agora.

Comment: Se possível teste este exemplo e veja se está abrindo e fechando ai na sua máquina. Aqui tb estou no 2016 e funcionou.... estranho....

Comment: E vi no comentário da outra resposta... de fato aqui fechará todas as instâncias do word abertas.... se o usuário tiver algo em aberto irá dar o comando de fechar também. Isso pode ser um problema. Por isso citei a necessidade de salvar antes. Se achar outra solução melhor poste para deixar o registro e aprendermos como fazer. Obrigado!

Comment: Então o problema deve ser o Bookmarks, pois mesmo dando quit nos dois continua aberto.

Answer (score 1):

### Sair e Definir o objeto do Word = Nothing

Você cria dois `objDoc` com `Set objDoc`. Depois no fim você fecha somente o último, enquanto o primeiro continua aberto.

Um programa VBA para fechar todos os arquivos de Word é o seguinte:

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/41100852/7690982
Option Explicit

Sub FecharDocWord()

    Dim objWord As Object

    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        If Not objWord Is Nothing Then
            objWord.Quit
            Set objWord = Nothing
        End If
    Loop Until objWord Is Nothing

End Sub
```

Créditos: [Robin Mackenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765395/robin-mackenzie)

### Matar a tarefa

Para fechar os processos no Gerenciador de Tarefas.

```
'http://vbadud.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/how-to-kill-word-process-using-vba.html
Sub Kill_Word()

Dim sKillWord As String 

sKillWord = "TASKKILL /F /IM Winword.exe" 

Shell sKillWord, vbHide 

End Sub
Read more at http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-kill-word-process-using-vba.html#yWeSjbJsIeyDBDDv.99
```

Comment: Mesmo que o QUIT funciona-se, eu não poderia utilizar esse recurso, pois  caso o usuário realmente esteja com o Word Aberto, iria fechar o trabalho do usuário.

Comment: Legal essa opção @danieltakeshi, valeu!!

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma solução, que ao menos Abre apenas 1 instancia do WINWORD no gerenciador de tarefas ou Utiliza a que já estiver aberta, já que a mesma não está fechando com o comando QUIT devido a utilização do Bookmarks (Provavelmente)

```
Sub DeleteSel(msg As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim objBkm As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objDoc = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If objDoc Is Nothing Then
        Set objDoc = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objDoc = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set objBkm = objDoc.Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig")

    If Not objBkm Is Nothing Then
        objBkm.Select
        objDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Delete
    End If

    objBkm.Quit
    objDoc.Quit
    Set objBkm = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Amigo, caso a resposta de sua pergunta tenha sido atendida pela nossa resposta, marque como respondida para referência futura de outros usuários.